# Синтаксическая ошибка в запросе к БД

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Выдает

```
     You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near "6" at line 1

$max = 6;
 "SELECT * FROM freinds WHERE id= '$id' ORDER BY last_visit DESC LIMIT '$max'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $query="SELECT * FROM freinds WHERE id= '".$id."' ORDER BY last_visit DESC LIMIT '".$max."'";
```

Лови ответ :)